# How to delete "Static" folder after npm run build without sudo?

Tags: node.js, bash, docker

I need to build docker. I have a Makefile and two DockerFiles (first for build FE container and second for nginx). During the build process, created `OUT` folder and on the compiling stage the "Static" folder created inside OUT folder. The result - docker works well.

In this case, after the build process, I need to remove OUT folder from local machine, but I can't do it without root permission. When I use command `rm -rf out` in the makefile I have an error with permissions:

```
rm -rf out                                                                                                        
rm: cannot remove 'out/static/css/479.0d9b8ebc.chunk.css': Permission denied
```

I see OUT folder created by local user and Static folder created by root user. If I add Sudo command - the folder is removed correctly, but I need to enter the user password manually each time I make a new docker.

Question:
**How to remove OUT folder after compilation?**

Makefile:

```
all: react-build web-app

DOCKERTAG?='cloud-interface:latest'
GIT_VERSION := $(shell git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always --tags)

web-app:
    echo $(GIT_VERSION) > version.html
    docker build -t $(DOCKERTAG) -f nginx-container/Dockerfile .
    rm -rf out
    docker rmi -f frontend-temp

react-build: build-container/Dockerfile web-application
    docker build -t frontend-temp -f build-container/Dockerfile .
    rm -rf out
    mkdir out
    docker run -it -v $(shell realpath out):/usr/bin/app/build frontend-temp bash -c "npm run build"

.PHONY: clean
```

Dockerfile build-container:

```bash
FROM node:16.17.0-bullseye-slim

#Copy application files

RUN mkdir -p /usr/bin/app
RUN npm install -g npm

COPY web-application/ /usr/bin/app/

WORKDIR /usr/bin/app

RUN npm install --force
#CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Dockerfile nginx-container:

```
FROM nginx
COPY out /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY version.html /usr/share/nginx/html/version.html
COPY nginx-container/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx-container/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY web-application/.env .
COPY web-application/env.sh .
RUN apt-get install bash
RUN chmod +x env.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My default way to approach this would be with a Docker-native approach, using a *multi-stage build*.  In a single Dockerfile, you can both build the front end and copy it into the final image.  This essentially works the same way as the Makefile you show, but it doesn't depend on copying the file content out to the host system, so you don't need to delete it later.

The Dockerfile looks almost like what you have, but with the two parts concatenated together into a single Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM node:16.17.0-bullseye-slim AS build
#                               ^^^^^^^^ give this stage a name

# Set up the container in basically the same way
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY web-application/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY web-application/ ./

# Make sure to actually build the source
RUN npm run build

# Final stage specifies the actual thing to run
FROM nginx

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# from the build image; using that image's filesystem path
...
```

With this setup you don't need to separately build the application, and the files don't exist on the host.  You also don't need to give a name to the build image.

It's probably enough to use just `docker build` to build the image.  But if you'd prefer to wrap it into a Makefile, you only need the one block.

```makefile
TAG := "latest"
IMAGE := "cloud-interface:$(TAG)"

all: .docker-build

.docker-build: version.html Dockerfile web-application/package.json
        docker build -t "$(IMAGE)" .
        touch "$@"

version.html:
        git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always --tags > "$@"

clean:
        rm -f version.html .docker-build

.PHONY: all clean
```

---

Your core permission problem in the original Dockerfile is that the process in the container by default runs as the root user.  You can specify an alternate user when you run the container, usually like

```bash
docker run -u $(id -u) ...
```

---

Another approach is to build the image and make sure to `RUN npm build` in the Dockerfile.  You can then `docker create` a temporary container (it does not need to actually run) and `docker cp` the files out of it, at which point they will be owned by the host user.

```makefile
all: .docker-web

.docker-react: build-container/Dockerfile
        docker build -t frontend-temp -f build-container/Dockerfile .
        touch "$@"

out/index.html: .docker-react
        docker create --name built frontend-temp
        rm -rf out
        mkdir out
        docker cp built:/usr/src/app/build/ out/
        docker rm built

.docker-web: out/index.html version.html nginx-container/Dockerfile
        docker build -t $(DOCKERTAG) -f nginx-container/Dockerfile .
        touch "$@"

clean:
        rm -f .docker-web .docker-react
        rm -rf out
        docker rmi frontend-temp || true
```

Comment: thank you for explain, I will try to do your recommendation!

Comment: Thank you again. Your solution is the best. I modified it a bit: `RUN npm ci` I changed to `RUN npm ci --legacy-peer-deps` and fixed path from `/usr/src/app` to `/usr/bin/app/`. First time my Jenkins can't build docker due to low performance. I increased resources and with 4 cores and 8 gb ram docker successfully was built.

Comment: hm... something went wrong: I successfully build FE application using your makefile and combined dockerfile, unfortunately I see cors error when I run it locally. In this case the FE do not use port 9000. But I specify it. Other words: my old code works fine, but I think , that something missed in your sample. Can you help me again?

Comment: I fixed it I add `WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html` row and now it works well.